# Errorlevel in a For loop (Windows batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, errorlevel

I have the following windows batch code:

```
for %%i in (iidbms iigcc iigcd dmfacp dmfrcp rmcmd qwerty) do (
  tasklist | findstr /i %%i
  echo %errorlevel%
  if %errorlevel% == 0 (echo %%i ok process found %errorlevel%)
  if %errorlevel% == 1 (echo %%i no process found %errorlevel%)
)
```

But it doesn't work as I expect.

All the name processes *iidbms*, *iigcc*, *iigcd*, *dmfacp*, *dmfrcp*, *rmcmd* are real, and they are found, instead *qwerty* is an invented one and should not find it, so should print **" no process found 1"**, but it doesn't, it always prints 0.

But what I have noted is that if I run the `tasklist | findstr /i qwerty` from the dos prompt, just after there is that the `%errorlevel%` = 1.

What sort of answer could be or better is?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

IF ERRORLEVEL returns TRUE if the return code was equal to or higher than the specified errorlevel. In your example, since 0 is lower than 1, the first errorlevel statement will always be true if the actual error code is 0 or above. What you want is to test for errorlevel 1 first.

E.g.:

```
for %%i in (iidbms iigcc iigcd dmfacp dmfrcp rmcmd qwerty) do (
    tasklist | findstr /i %%i
    if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo process
    if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo process not found
)
```

Another issue is if you want to echo the actual errorlevel from within the for loop. Since variables are resolved before the start of the loop, echoing `%errorlevel%` will always echo 0. If you want to echo the value at the execution time, you need to modify the snippet like so:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (iidbms iigcc iigcd dmfacp dmfrcp rmcmd qwerty) do (
    tasklist | findstr /i %%i
    if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo %%i ok process found !errorlevel!
    if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo %%i no process found !errorlevel!
)
```

Answer (score 42):

Add

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

to the start of your script, then use
`!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
> time rather than at parse time
>
> ~ http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

The answer to another question that pointed me in the right direction:
[Errorlevel of command executed by batch for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088712/850848#6658935)

Answer (score -1):

You can use vbscript,

```
NumArgs = WScript.Arguments.Count
strComputer="."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    For i=0 To NumArgs-1
        If InStr( objProcess.Name ,WScript.Arguments(i)  ) > 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "found:" & WScript.Arguments(i)
        End If 
    Next 
Next
```

Usage:

```
C:\test>cscript //nologo test.vbs explorer spool svchost
found:svchost
found:svchost
found:svchost
found:svchost
found:svchost
found:explorer
found:svchost
found:spool
```