# errorlevel works on one server but not other

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, errorlevel

I have two Windows 2008 SP2 servers, one dev other production. Production has Microsoft CLuster services running. Now in one particular batch script following commands are there:

```
dsmc incr "%ARCHIVE_DIR%\*"
if errorlevel 1 goto EXCPT
more code to do purging

Excpt:
echo "script backup error"
```

In dev this works as expected, dsmc incr returns 8 on successful completion and script moves to purging code. However in production even though dsmc incr return 8, the errorlevel always evaluates to 1 and it jumps to Excpt: . Can anyone help on this please ?

Comment: I have an update, the dsmc incr returns 0 on dev and return code 8 in production. so it makes sense as per [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942265/errorlevel-in-a-for-loop-batch-windows) if errorlevel 1 mean that errorlevel is greater than or equal to 1 not just one.

Comment: Correct it in your question!

Answer (score 1):

Check `IF` help!

```
 `IF /?`
```

You will find:

> ERRORLEVEL (...) Specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number specified.

So,

```
if errorlevel 1 ...
```

will evaluate true for any errorlevel>=1.

To get exact matching, use:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 ...
```

or

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 ...
```

Last one will not work on environments where `ERRORLEVEL` is used as environment variable.