# batch ERRORLEVEL always 0

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, errorlevel

I'm facing an issue when trying to implement the `ERRORLEVEL` on my batch script. Basically what I'm trying to do is: look for the `.txt` files in the directory and if found; `.txt` will get listed, if not found; message error will occur.

The thing is that this directory will not always contain a `.txt`, sometimes it will be empty and when that happens my code will not work. Only when there is a `.txt` in the directory I'm getting my conditions to work (`ERRORLEVEL = 0`), but if empty; none of my conditions will. Not even the `ERRORLEVEL` will be printed in the cmd screen (I should see it as `ERRORLEVEL = 1`).

This is my code:

```
for /r "C:\Texts" %%a in (*.txt) do ( 
echo %errorlevel%
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (    
    echo %%a
    echo "I found your Text!"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "I couldn`t find your Text!" )
    )
```

What exactly is wrong with my `ERRORLEVEL` implementation?

Comment: Take a look at [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). But it also looks like you forgot a find command.

Comment: I think you might find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3942468/221005 helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Errorlevel 0 is always true.

Use

```
if not errorlevel 1
```

But your code doesn't set the errorlevel.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is not any command that set the errorlevel. This value is set by all external .exe commands (like `find` or `findstr`), and by certain specific internal commands (like `verify` that set errorlevel=1 when its parameter is wrong, or `ver` that always set the errorlevel=0.

You may explicitly set this value in your code this way:

```
rem Set the errorlevel to 1
verify bad 2> NUL

for /r "C:\Texts" %%a in (*.txt) do (
   echo %%a
   rem Set the errorlevel to 0
   ver > NUL
)

if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   echo "I found your Text!"
) else (
   echo "I couldn't find your Text!"
)
```

However, you may also get a similar result using a Batch variable instead of the errorlevel...

Comment: This did it!! thanks a lot. I know see where I was failing