# Compare two file and get the result into another file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have two text files: 
Last_RUN_Result.txt has:

```
AAAA
BBBB
```

The New_RUN_Result.txt has:

```
AAAA
CCCC
```

I need a Compare_Result.txt has:

```
AAAA
```

So I used the script as below:

```
        REM Search New_RUN_Result.txt's instance name in Last_RUN_Result.txt
rem         DEL Compare_Result.txt
        echo. 2>Compare_Result.txt
        for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%j in (New_RUN_Result.txt) do (
            FIND /c "%%j" Last_RUN_Result.txt
            IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
                echo.%%j >> Compare_Result.txt
            ) 
        )
```

But I will get:

```
AAAA
CCCC
```

Could you please help me out of this?
Thank you for your time:)

Comment: You should be able to do such a simple match with one single `FINDSTR` command. `FINDSTR /G:New_RUN_Result.txt Last_RUN_Result.txt` . And the problem with your code is that you are inside a parenthesized code block.  You need to use delayed expansion if you want to use the variable !errorlevel!. Looking back at your previous questions, delayed expansion has been mentioned to you several times.  If you still do not understand how it works please update your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: Thank you Squashman, It works! Much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errorlevel in a For loop (batch windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942265/errorlevel-in-a-for-loop-batch-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fc command. `Fc file1 file2` If you are looking for a way to easily separate new and old lines I could upload a tool called `lc.exe` which compares two files and puts lines unique to one file one in a doc `old.txt` and lines unique to the other in `new.txt` let me know if this still doesn’t answer your question or if you want the lc file. EDIT: Here is the LC.exe file https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlRLV33Rdz2CgrgfJLPN7GhkfV-KkA